# How to make legend labels to bring out the series of a pie chart and not make them disappear when label is clicked in HighCharts?

Tags: highcharts, label, pie-chart, series

I have following chart http://jsfiddle.net/dbahiense/enmqyv0p/ made with HighCharts.

Here the js code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            useHTML: true,
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
        },

        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },

            legend: {
                enabled: true,
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                useHTML: true,
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
            },

        series: [{
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   44.2],
                ['IE7',       26.6],
                ['IE6',       20],
                ['Chrome',    3.1],
                ['Other',    5.4]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

When I click on any **series** direct on the chart or on **its label** (connected to the chart by a thin coloured line) the corresponding part of the pie moves out and when I click on it again it moves in. In the other side when I click on the **legend** the corresponding series of the pie disappears/appears. I know this is what we should expect.

What I really like to know is what I have to do, so when I click on one of the labels of the legend (list of browsers on the left) it doesn't disappears, but moves out.

I've already tried to change/insert legend.enable, plotOptions.pie.dataLabels, pie.selecte, pie.showInLegend and options but without success.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the legend item click event on the point level for pie charts.  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.point.events.legendItemClick

```
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            showInLegend: true,
            point: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        this.select();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I stopped the default from happening and fired the point select event.
http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/enmqyv0p/4/